# XSLT Transformation from SQL to XML

Tags: xml, xslt

i have the following problem:

I'm using the a SQL-Statement with

```
<table name="VDR_10" namecase="lower">
        <sql><![CDATA[" SQL-Select "]]></sql>
</table>
```

to get the following table

```
    P1  P2  ident
    3   702 XS0419605406
    3   702 XS0188568751
    4   702 XXXXXXXXXXXX
    4   702 XS1048428012
    3   701 AT0000A0N9A0
    3   701 XS0418690201
    3   701 XS0417728325
    3   701 BE0000314238
    3   701 ES0000101339
```

My xslt is looking like this:

```
    <xsl:key name="vdr10_kennzahl" match="VDR_10" use="p2"/>

    <xsl:template match="VDR_10">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$this[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('vdr10_kennzahl', p2))]">
            <xsl:sort select="p2" order="ascending"/>
            <POSTEN>
                <xsl:attribute name="p1-id"><xsl:value-of select="p1"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="p2-id"><xsl:value-of select="p2"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('vdr10_kennzahl',p2)">
                    <IDENT-Zeile>
                        <BETRAG>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ident"/>
                        </BETRAG>
                    </IDENT-ZEILE>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </POSTEN>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

The output is looking like this:

```
    <POSTEN p1-id="3" p2-id ="702"> 
        <IDENT-zeile>XS0419605406</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>XS0188568751</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>XXXXXXXXXXXX</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>XS1048428012</IDENT-zeile>
    </POSTEN>   


    <POSTEN p1-id="3" p2-id ="701"> 
        <IDENT-zeile>AT0000A0N9A0</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>XS0418690201</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>XS0417728325</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>BE0000314238</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>ES0000101339</IDENT-zeile>
    </POSTEN>
```

And that is not what i want. I need ´the output like this

```
    <POSTEN p1-id="3" p2-id ="702"> 
        <IDENT-zeile>XS0419605406</IDENT-zeile> 
        <IDENT-zeile>XS0188568751</IDENT-zeile>
    </POSTEN>   

    <POSTEN p1-id="4" p2-id ="702"> 
        <IDENT-zeile>XXXXXXXXXXXX</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>XS1048428012</IDENT-zeile>
    </POSTEN>

    <POSTEN p1-id="3" p2-id ="701">     
        <IDENT-zeile>AT0000A0N9A0</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>XS0418690201</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>XS0417728325</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>BE0000314238</IDENT-zeile>
        <IDENT-zeile>ES0000101339</IDENT-zeile>
    </POSTEN>
```

I think i need an other for-each. But i have no clue how to use it. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are currently grouping only on the "p2" value, when you need to group on both "p1" and "p2". Therefore your key needs to look like this

```
<xsl:key name="vdr10_kennzahl" match="VDR_10" use="concat(p1, '|', p2)"/>
```

You would use the "concat" wherever you then accessed the key

```
 <xsl:for-each 
     select="$this[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('vdr10_kennzahl', concat(p1, '|', p2)))]">
```

Having said that, that **xsl:for-each** is a bit unnecessary, as it will only ever return one value for the current **VDR_10** being matched. Better to have the condition on the template match itself, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="VDR_10[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('vdr10_kennzahl', concat(p1, '|', p2)))]">
```

You would also need another template to match all other **VDR_10** elements, to ignore them

```
<xsl:template match="VDR_10" />
```

(The more specific template will always get priority here).

Finally, if you want the results sorted, you would add the logic to the parent element, and select the child nodes in sorted order

```
<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="VDR_10">
      <xsl:sort select="p1" />
      <xsl:sort select="p2" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

For example, try this XSLT (Note the use of Attribute Value Templates in created the "p1-id" and "p2-id" attributes, to reduce the size of the XSLT)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="vdr10_kennzahl" match="VDR_10" use="concat(p1, '|', p2)"/>


    <xsl:template match="table">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="VDR_10">
          <xsl:sort select="p1" />
          <xsl:sort select="p2" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="VDR_10[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('vdr10_kennzahl', concat(p1, '|', p2)))]">
       <POSTEN p1-id="{p1}" p2-id="{p2}">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('vdr10_kennzahl',concat(p1, '|', p2))">
                <IDENT-zeile>
                      <xsl:value-of select="ident"/>
                 </IDENT-zeile>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </POSTEN>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="VDR_10" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML

```
<table>
    <VDR_10><p1>3</p1><p2>702</p2><ident>XS0419605406</ident></VDR_10>
    <VDR_10><p1>3</p1><p2>702</p2><ident>XS0188568751</ident></VDR_10>
    <VDR_10><p1>4</p1><p2>702</p2><ident>XXXXXXXXXXXX</ident></VDR_10>
    <VDR_10><p1>4</p1><p2>702</p2><ident>XS1048428012</ident></VDR_10>
    <VDR_10><p1>3</p1><p2>701</p2><ident>AT0000A0N9A0</ident></VDR_10>
    <VDR_10><p1>3</p1><p2>701</p2><ident>XS0418690201</ident></VDR_10>
    <VDR_10><p1>3</p1><p2>701</p2><ident>XS0417728325</ident></VDR_10>
    <VDR_10><p1>3</p1><p2>701</p2><ident>BE0000314238</ident></VDR_10>
    <VDR_10><p1>3</p1><p2>701</p2><ident>ES0000101339</ident></VDR_10>
</table>
```

The following is output

```
<POSTEN p1-id="3" p2-id="701">
  <IDENT-zeile>AT0000A0N9A0</IDENT-zeile>
  <IDENT-zeile>XS0418690201</IDENT-zeile>
  <IDENT-zeile>XS0417728325</IDENT-zeile>
  <IDENT-zeile>BE0000314238</IDENT-zeile>
  <IDENT-zeile>ES0000101339</IDENT-zeile>
</POSTEN>
<POSTEN p1-id="3" p2-id="702">
  <IDENT-zeile>XS0419605406</IDENT-zeile>
  <IDENT-zeile>XS0188568751</IDENT-zeile>
</POSTEN>
<POSTEN p1-id="4" p2-id="702">
  <IDENT-zeile>XXXXXXXXXXXX</IDENT-zeile>
  <IDENT-zeile>XS1048428012</IDENT-zeile>
</POSTEN>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. Thats it.